# Dynamically Add Images to Slider jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Drop-down by Categories.I have 20 images in Cat1 and 30 images in Cat2 so on..
this images are from JSON web service. I have Parsed api, Result content i have added to array. So When Cat1 is Selected from DropDown the images will load correctly but when select cat2 then they are not showing.

What i have done is iam sending the images array to this function when categorie is selected, Were iam Constructing html string with images from array by looping them then adding to the mcts1 div element,

```
function createIcons(imagesArray) {
    console.log(imagesArray);
    var iconsDict = imagesArray;
    var output = '';
    var foo = (iconsDict);
    for (var i = 0; i < iconsDict.length; i++) {
        output += '<img class="icons" id=' + i + ' src=' + foo[i] + ' width="100px" height="100px"/>';
    }
    $("#mcts1").html(output); 

}
```

Here is my html,

```
<div class="div2">
      <div id="mcts1">

      </div>
    </div>
```

iam using menucool slider [here is the link](http://www.menucool.com/jquery-slider)

Comment: can u [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/) your code

Answer (score 0):

You Dynamically modify the jQuery Slider so follow this steps

HTML

```
<div id="mcts1"></div>
```

Script

```
   <script type=”text/javascript”>
 function addSlides(str)
{ var sliderElm = document.getElementById(“mcts1”); 
sliderElm.innerHTML = str; 
} 
</script>
```

After getting output from your function call like this

```
 addSlides(output);
```

Comment: try this way every change `empty()` the div then append your output then call this function `ThumbnailSlider(mct1_Options)` comment your output

Comment: $("mcts1").empty();    
    addSlides(output);
    ThumbnailSlider(mct1_Options);                                  output is : Uncaught ReferenceError: ThumbnailSlider is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Its working for me

```
var html = "";
for(var i = 0; i <= images_array.length - 1; i++)
{
    html += "<img src='"+images_array[i]+"' class='sliderImage' id='image_"+i+"' />";
}
$("#slider").append(html);
```